# How to mount folder with files in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

I am running a docker image that has certain configuration files within it. I need to persist/mount the same folder to the disk as new files will get added later on. When I use standard volume mount in kubernetes, it mounts an empty directory without the intial configuration files. How do I make sure my initial files are copied to the volume while mounting?

````
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: my-vol
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: my-vol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wso2-disk2```
````

Comment: That sounds like you're looking for a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).  You wouldn't generally try to "mount a folder" as you're describing; among other reasons, it's tricky to ensure that it exists with the same content on every node in the cluster.

Comment: This is an operating system/utilities question and not a programming question. Questions about Docker and Kubernetes need to be programming related and not about configuration.

Comment: @DavidMaze Will config map work if I have combination of different kinds of files in my config directory?

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution could be the use the node storage mounted on containers (easiest way) or using a DFS solution like NFS, GlusterFS, and so on.

Another and recommended way to achieve what you need is to use a persistent volumes to share the same files between your containers.

Assuming you have a kubernetes cluster that has only one Node, and you want to share the path `/mtn/data` of your node with your pods ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60092545/12153576)):

**Create a PersistentVolume:**

> A hostPath PersistentVolume uses a file or directory on the Node to emulate network-attached storage.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

**Create a PersistentVolumeClaim:**

> Pods use PersistentVolumeClaims to request physical storage

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Look at the PersistentVolumeClaim:

`kubectl get pvc task-pv-claim`

The output shows that the PersistentVolumeClaim is bound to your PersistentVolume,  `task-pv-volume`.

```
NAME            STATUS    VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
task-pv-claim   Bound     task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO           manual         30s
```

**Create a deployment with 2 replicas for example:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
      containers:
        - name: task-pv-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: "http-server"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
              name: task-pv-storage
```

Now you can check inside both container the path `/mnt/data` has the same files.

If you have cluster with more than 1 node I recommend you to think about the other types of [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) or using [DFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/).

**References:**
[Configure persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)
[Persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)
[Volume Types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes)

Comment: This doesn't address my problem. My issue is that i need to mount a directory that already has files (In the image). But kubernetes mounts an empty volume instead.

Comment: @Pranav hi, 
did you solve this problem? i face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Create configmap of the folder you would like to mount, the following creates configmap consisting of all the files in **your-folder**:

```
kubectl create configmap your-config --from-file=your-folder/
```

Then mount this to the volume and you will have the initial files in your folder. And note that you will need to mount it to **subpath** since you dont want it to overwrite everything in the directory.

Comment: Can you mount a folder with whatever files? I have tried and only configuration files like *.yaml and *.properties, for instance, are taken into account.

Comment: Yes you can, I would do this by creating a folder in the pod's container with similar name as the one I would like to mount. Then create a configmap of all the files in the folder (just like I commented above), and mount it to the folder that I created in the pod(use subpath of mount folder). In fact this is how I usually do it.

Comment: Really thanks @Zstack, I was just running `kubectl describe configmaps configuration` and only the yaml files where shown, not other files with extensions like .zip or .jar, but mounting as a volume to a subpath shown all the files.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested way to provide configurations to your pod is by creating a `configmap` for your configurations and mount it in your pod using volumes. This guide ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) descibes how to do that.

Other ways are to create a `persistent volume` and `persistent volume claim` in your cluster and copy your configuration file in that path. Mount the persistent volume in your pod.

You can also copy your configuration on one of the nodes in your cluster and mount that path using `hostPath` but this requires that your pod should also run on the same node as it tries to look for the path in that node. (Not a recommended approach)